# What differs between the Cervelo S5 and S5VWD

Tags: frames

Looking at the Cervelo S5 series there are two different models but the [Cervelo page](http://www.cervelo.com/en/bikes/s-series/s5.html) offers no mention of what differences are.. could someone enlighten me? Looking just at the framesets is there a difference?

Comment: Down voted why?

Answer (score 1):

They are different frames, with the VWD being lighter than the normal one. It is claimed that other properties (stiffness, comfort, shape) are the same, though.

[This thread](http://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=108742), in particular the post by em3, point to the following links from Cervelo: [a](http://forums.cervelo.com/forums/p/8604/59656.aspx#59656),[b](http://forums.cervelo.com/forums/t/8315.aspx?PageIndex=1).

Comment: So, let me get this straight, they use less material, are are able to charge $2000 (57%) more?  The frames are basically the same identical shape, so the work to create either one should be about the same.  People sure will pay a lot for a little bit of weight savings.

Comment: There isn't really logic to weight weenie-ing, now is there? I wouldn't say its just less material, but a different carbon fiber weave/layup or whatever to get the same shape at a lower weight while claiming the ride characteristics don't change.

Comment: @Kibbee yep, you've only got to look at carbon pedals to see that. The bike manufacturers will charge whatever they can get away with in the marketplace. Sad but true. Cervelo in particular has a very good name.

Comment: @PeteH Personally, I think the [$100 water bottle cage](http://www.amazon.com/Campagnolo-Super-Record-Cage-Includes/dp/B009CH0NDQ) is the pinnacle of charging what they can get away with. Especially considering a $5 plastic bottle cage will probably weigh about the same, maybe with an additional 5-10 grams.

Comment: @Kibbee in fairness, you do get a free bottle ;)

Comment: So slightly lighter, same ride and stiffness qualities, higher price tag - all thanks to some different carbon fibre technology, and a very slightly different paint job. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Kibbee it is a Campagnolo bottle cage though. Therefore it allows the overweight & overpaid mamil on the bike which is adorned in a $100 cage the right look down judgementally upon any young whippersnapper with a plastic or aluminium cage, while said mamil desperately tries to cling on to said whippersnapper's back wheel... therefore it's good value ;)